# Zap logger values

Tags: go, go-zap

Hello I want to use zap global logger

right now I am using like this

```
        zap.L().Error("error receive",
            zap.Error(err),
            zap.String("uuid", msg.Id)
            zap.String("msg_f", msg_f),
        )
```

but the only problem is I am getting errors because of types of uuid and msg

```
type Message struct {
    Id   uuid.UUID
}
```

and msg_f type is []byte my question how can I print them but I don't what should I use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of [`zap.String`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#String) is:

```golang
func String(key string, val string) Field
```

So the second argument is a `string`; a `UUID`/`[]byte` is not a `string` so cannot be used as-is. This leaves you with two options:

- Pass a `string` to `zap.String` (converting what you have into a `string`) or;
- Use a function that accepts the type you want to log.

zap provides a number of functions that return a `Field` some of which accept `[]byte` (e.g. [`Binary`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Binary) and [`ByteString`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#ByteString). zap also provides [`Stringer`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/zap#Stringer) which you can use with any type that implements the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Stringer) interface (which `UUID` does).

The below ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/T_Dnne4w3Ji)) demonstrates:

```golang
zap.L().Error("error receive",
        zap.Error(err),
        zap.String("uuid", msg.Id.String()),
        zap.Stringer("uuid2", msg.Id),
        zap.ByteString("msg_f", msg_f),
        zap.Binary("msg_f2", msg_f),
        zap.String("msg_f3", string(msg_f)),
    )
```